# Servlet 3.0 streaming api for file upload

Tags: java, file-upload, servlet-3.0

New Servlet 3.0 API provide us with convenient way to parse multi-part form data. But it stores content of uploaded files in file system or in memory

Is there streaming API for Servlet 3.0 ?

Something like  [Commons FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/streaming.html). I have to write content directly from InputStream and write to another OutputStream adn I don't want to store temporary file content in disc or memory

Comment: Have you found the solution?

Answer (score 1):

I used this once for something similar, though not with servlets. It doesn't fill up your memory with data. Hope it helps:
http://code.google.com/p/io-tools/wiki/Tutorial_EasyStream

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the Servlet 3.0 spec it may not be possible to have a streaming implementation

> For parts with form-data as the Content-Disposition, but without a
>   filename, the string value of the part will also be available via the
>   getParameter /getParameterValues methods on HttpServletRequest, using
>   the name of the part.

So the request must be parsed up front so that all the non-file parts can be exposed as HttpServletRequest parameters.

You have to use third party libraries if you need streaming.